# How can i check database table if new data is inserted or not with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose a new data is inserted into database table. I will not insert data. Others will insert data. A php script will be run, then it will say "A new data is inserted into database table". How can i do it with php pdo?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a kind of trigger whenever any data get's inserted or just a PHP script, inserting data and echoing "New Data ..." after success ...?

Comment: A kind of trigger whenever any data gets inserted, then if i refresh the webpage/(notification.php) it will notify that a new data is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have binary logging enabled, you'll be able to [get the exact insertion time from mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-mysql-database.html) compare the results of this to the baseline timestamp. If true, Bob's your uncle. If you don't have binary logging enabled, though, I'm afraid you're up the creek without a paddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger like 
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Notify
    ON  dbo.Table
    AFTER INSERT
AS....

insert message (A new data is inserted into database table) in new tables and read that table to check it.

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation , what you are looking for is to return the number of rows affected.

It can be archieved calling `rowCount(`)

```
<?php
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$del->execute();

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Return number of rows that were deleted:\n");
$count = $del->rowCount();
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

The full example plus the documentation can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php